# Google sign in not working on published app

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I develop an app and I published yesterday night, I download my app and I try to sign in with google account but it's not working but I can sign in with google when I try to debug on my code. How can it's possible, where is my wrong?
[image]

Comment: Please connect device to Android studio, you may get error logs, paste it here

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it works for me

Step 1) Project Structure -> select project -> go to "signing" and select default or any keystore and fill proper details. In case you are not able to fill the details, click the green '+' button. Step 2) Goto Build Types -> select your build type and select your "Signing Config"-> select "config". Step 3) Create new SHA-1 key and add in google console credential.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add your SHA-1 key to the google cloud console project

check this for help - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 1):

You need add release apk sha1. If you added sha1 when your app in debugMode it will only work on Debug APK. So you have to create a sha1 by your release APK keystore,

keytool -exportcert -keystore keystorePath -list -v